# una Ventana durante ejecución del programa phyton

Tags: python, messagebox

Ante todo comentar que soy novato en programación en Python...
He realizado un programa que me gestiona tres hojas excel de unos 8000 registros cada una, y me da como resultado otras tantas... y funciona correctamente, aunque a mi parecer va un poco lento (tarda unos 110 sg..)

Pero lo que me gustaría es poder poner una ventana al inicio del programa que indique "En ejecución" y cuando termine, se cierre y me aparezca otra que diga "proceso terminado".

Mi problema es que se abre la primera ventana, pero el proceso no se ejecuta hasta que le doy a aceptar, y yo lo que quiero es que se quede abierta, mientras se ejecuta el programa, y cuando termine se cierre y me salga la otra...

dejo un ejemplo del código... le puse un temporizador para probar..

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showinfo(message="En ejecución", title="Título")
a=1000
b=0
while b<1000:
    print (b)
    b +=1
messagebox.showinfo(message="Proceso terminado", title="Título")
```

como ven el código no se ejecuta hasta que cierras la primera..
Gracias..

Comment: Python es monohilo, lo que implica que ciertos procesos son bloqueantes (como `showbox`). Lo que intentas hacer requiere de alguna librería que simule multi hilo, como `threading` o `asyncio`

Comment: Gracias, mirare por ese lado...